MLNET Models not convert to Onnx
I am using ML.NET for Image Classification, but I am encountering high CPU usage, consuming up to 70% of CPU resources. I want to switch to GPU (NVIDIA GTX 1030), but ML.NET either does not support GPU or it is not functioning correctly (I'm not sure which one).
I tried converting my model to ONNX to utilize the GPU fully, but I keep getting errors when converting. I have tried replacing different versions of ONNX Convert, but none seem to work.
Here is my code:
public (MLContext ML_CT, ITransformer ITRANS, IDataView IDATAV) Train_MLNET_Auto1st()
{
    // Status logging and context creation
    STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LB_Conten($"Loop: ");
    STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LABEL(STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LabelStatus.Build);
    var mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 1);
    mlContext.Log += FilterMLContextLog;

    IDataView datainput = LoadImageFromFolder(mlContext, ui_main.Folder_Train);

    var options = Option.Select_Option(datainput, ui_main.TENSORFLOW);
    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "Label", addKeyValueAnnotationsAsText: false)
        .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(labelColumnName: "Label", scoreColumnName: "Score", featureColumnName: "ImageSource"))
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(outputColumnName: "PredictedLabel", inputColumnName: "PredictedLabel"));

    LOGGER_INFORMATION.LogInformation("*** Training the image classification model with DNN Transfer Learning on top of the selected pre-trained model/architecture ***");

    // Measure training time
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Train the model
    STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LABEL(STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LabelStatus.Train);
    ITransformer bestModel = pipeline.Fit(datainput);

    try
    {
        // Try converting the model to ONNX format
        using (var onnx = File.Open("mymodel.onnx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            mlContext.Model.ConvertToOnnx(bestModel, datainput, onnx);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LOGGER_INFORMATION.LogWarning("Error converting to ONNX: " + ex);
    }

    // Evaluate the model
    STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LABEL(STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LabelStatus.Evaluate);
    var bestMetrics = EvaluateModel_Eval(mlContext, datainput, bestModel);
    BestModelScore = bestMetrics;

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    LOGGER_INFORMATION.LogInformation($"Training with transfer learning took: {elapsedMs / 1000} seconds");

    // Update status and return the model
    STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LABEL(STATUS_TRAIN_ML.LabelStatus.Consume);
    return (mlContext, bestModel, datainput);
}

Error: I tried replacing different versions of ONNX Convert, but none seem to work.
I found a fixable problem here
C# ML.Net Image classification: Does GPU acceleration help improve the performance of predictions and how can I tell if it is?

You have to tell us the errors, we cannot guess them.
